# Gun keeps firing before the player is finished rotating

Tags: unity, 2d, raycasting, coroutines

I have a script that manages player rotation and shooting. When I click on an enemy, the player is supposed to turn toward the enemy and then shoot in the direction they are facing. However, the bullet keeps firing in the direction that the player was facing before the rotation.

```
void Turn(){
        mousePos = cam.ScreenToWorldPoint(Input.mousePosition);
        rb.MovePosition(rb.position + movement * speed * Time.fixedDeltaTime);
        Vector2 lookDir = mousePos - rb.position;
        float angle = Mathf.Atan2(lookDir.y, lookDir.x) * Mathf.Rad2Deg -90f;
        rb.rotation = angle;
    }

    void Shoot()
    {
        if(allowFire){
          StartCoroutine(FireRate());
        }
        
    }
    IEnumerator FireRate()
    {
            allowFire = false;
            GameObject bullet = Instantiate(bulletPrefab, firePoint.position, firePoint.rotation);
            Destroy(bullet, 3);
            Rigidbody2D rb = bullet.GetComponent<Rigidbody2D>();
            rb.AddForce(firePoint.up * bulletForce, ForceMode2D.Impulse);
            yield return new WaitForSeconds(1/(fireRate/2));
            allowFire = true;
    }
```

Below is the code in update that calls these methods

````
if(Input.GetMouseButton(1)){
            Turn();
            RaycastHit2D hit = Physics2D.Raycast(Camera.main.ScreenToWorldPoint(Input.mousePosition), Vector2.zero);
            if(hit.collider != null){         
                if (hit.transform.tag == "Enemy") 
                {
                    isMoving = false;
                    Shoot();
                }
```
````

Comment: Where is firePoint defined? Do you need to update that value before instantiating the bullet?

Comment: I ran into something similar in my tower defense game. I will recommend checking the angle difference between the weapon and your enemy location. If the angle is less or equal some min angle, then fire.

Comment: Are you sure firepoint is a child of rb?